# Rails Game Loop in Application Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, game-loop

Since i'm writing a game in RoR, i need to have a game loop that is responsible for checking different things every time a page refresh happens. My question is, what is the best way to implement ?

I currently include the game_loop in my application controller. Is this the best practice ?

Comment: Not sure if there is a common best practice for this, but yes, if you need to do things every time on every page, having it in the application controller seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the game look as a [`before_filter`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000316) in your `ApplicationController` sounds reasonable, although you may not wish to put your logic in this class:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :do_game_loop

  private

    def do_game_loop
      Game.do_game_loop # the implementation of Game is in another file, maybe in lib
    end
end
```

Do note that this will execute the game loop before *every* action in your application that involves a controller that extends from `ApplicationController`, including user login, logout, etc. It may be better to add the `before_filter` only in the controllers that definitely need to process the game loop.

Comment: yeap, i was doing the exact same thing. Thanx.